# Django 2.2: How to redirect a user from a view to a specific page with a context?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Our website is listing properties ads.

When a user publish an ad, I would like to redirect him to a "thank you" page. But inside this thank you page I would like to put a button with the link to the detailed view of the created ad.

I don't want to use "messages" framework because I need a dedicated page for tracking purpose.

How can I send the context (in this case the absolute url of the created object) to the "thank you" page?

It doesn't matter if the solution requires the use of a class based view or a function view.

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: You can pass the `ad.id` in the url of your thank-you page and redirect to the DetailView of your `ad` object from there. Is that what you want (sending id alongside with url)?

Comment: Or put the data in the session.

Comment: you can create a list view with filter, so that the publisher can see the his last published item. Give this link in your thank you page and from the that last item link to the detail page.

Comment: @PedramParsian how do you do that? :) sending the id could be enough in order to built the absolute URI. Thank you!

Comment: @DanielRoseman maybe this is the « cleanest » solution. I’m going to search for documentation about django Sessions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found a clean solution.

In my view I redirect to a success page and pass a parameter. In the urls.py I setup the path of the success page in order to take the parameter in the URL. Then I can use the data passed to the success page.

**in views.py using class based views**

```
def post(self, request):
    my_param = my_param
    return redirect('success', param=my_param)
```

**in urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('success/<str:param>/', Success.as_view(), name='success'),
]
```

Hope this will help. It seems basic but it took me some time to figure out what I was looking for :)